# When clicking on a notification button the notification count is set to 0.when re-render the count is set to like before how to prevent this situation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react components for navbar which contains notification button like Facebook I want to implement function like Facebook as it has a notification button with notification count & when click on the button the notification count is disappear till now all is ok, but when the components re-render the notification count re-appear like before. How can I prevent this problem?

`

```
  const { data: allAnnouncements, refetch } = useLoadPublicData(announcementsURL);

  const [announcementCount, setAnnouncementCount] = useState(0)
  const [oldAnnouncementCount, setOldAnnouncementCount] = useState(0)
  const [newAnnouncementCount, setNewAnnouncementCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnnouncementCount(allAnnouncements?.length)
    refetch();
  }, [announcementCount, refetch, allAnnouncements]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(announcementCount > oldAnnouncementCount){
      const newAnnouncements = announcementCount - oldAnnouncementCount
      setNewAnnouncementCount(newAnnouncements)
      setOldAnnouncementCount(announcementCount)
    }
  }, [announcementCount, oldAnnouncementCount]);

  console.log(newAnnouncementCount);

const handleNewAnnouncement = () => {
  setNewAnnouncementCount(0)
}

<>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      </li>
      {dbUser?.badge === "bronze" && (
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/membership">Membership</NavLink>
        </li>
      )}
      <li>
        <div className="text-right">
          <Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left">
            <NavLink>
              <Menu.Button onClick={handleNewAnnouncement} className="relative text-white ">
                <IoMdNotifications className="text-2xl"></IoMdNotifications>
                {newAnnouncementCount > 0 && (
                  <p className="absolute -top-2 -right-1 rounded-full bg-red-500 px-1 tew">
                    {newAnnouncementCount}
                  </p>
                )}
              </Menu.Button>
            </NavLink>
            <Transition
              as={Fragment}
              enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
              enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
              leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-96 origin-top-right divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black/5 focus:outline-none">
                <div className="px-1 py-4 space-y-2">
                  {
                    allAnnouncements?.map(announcement => <Menu.Item key={announcement?._id}>
                      {({ active }) => (
                        <button
                          className={`${
                            active ? "bg-primary text-white flex items-center gap-4" : "text-gray-900"
                          } group flex w-full items-center rounded-md px-2 py-2 text-sm gap-4`}
                        >
                          <img className="w-10 rounded-full" src={announcement?.photoURL} alt="" />
                          <p>{announcement?.title}</p>
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </Menu.Item>)
                  }
                </div>
              </Menu.Items>
            </Transition>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </li>
    </>`
```